# Issue in UIViewController push & pop

Tags: iphone, ios, release, dealloc, pushviewcontroller

I've facing an issue of push & pop my UIViewController. I've two UIViewControllers say `A` & `B`.

I have written an `IBAction` in which I pushing to `B` from `A` like,

```
B *bView=[[B alloc] initWithNibName:@"B" bundle:nil];
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animation" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.7];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:bView animated:NO];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];

[bView release]; //Problem is here, If I comment this line, it works fine! else it crashes after my some transitions from A [push] B, B [pop] A.
```

Now in `B` I've written an `IBAction` to pop to `A` like below

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"animation" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.7];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I have also calling `[super dealloc]` from `B`

```
-(void) dealloc
{
   [super dealloc];
}
```

**If  I don't  release `bView` it will not call dealloc, and may creates issues of memory.**

**Is this problem because of animation I applying?**

I tried with all other ways like `autorelease`, set `bView=nil;` etc. but those won't work for me!

Any help, suggestion!

Comment: There is no problem with [bView release]; There is something else which is wrong in your Class B code, you can use NSZombie to track where exactly the issue is. Or you can paste code for your class B.

Comment: NSZombie is enabled, it shows message that, `message sent to deallocated reference`

Comment: it will show some memory address, on console you can use "po memory-address" and see which instance is causing this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try releasing `bView` inside the animation completion block instead.

You can use old style `+ setAnimationDidStopSelector:`
or if you don't need to support pre iOS4 devices, you can use animation blocks `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:`